# Chess Software for analysis and notes

Tags: engines, software, annotation

I am looking for software that has chess engine analysis but also allows me to take notes and save games. I have used Scid in the past for this and liked it, but I just want to see if there is something better out there.

Comment: Fritz from Chessbase?

Comment: Fritz is a good choice too and I may think about using it. The only downside is the high price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old Fritz 5.32 (last free version) does this. Of course it is not as powerful as the latest version (big understatement). It is available here http://freechess.50webs.com/fritz.html but note that it will need some work (described on the website) to get it to run on modern versions of Windows.

I alternate between Fritz 8, which is not quite as old as the free version and runs on modern operating systems, and [Scid vs PC](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/) which is a much more modern fork of Scid and could also be worth trying especially if you are still stuck on original Scid.

Comment: You've missed Arena.

Comment: You've also missed [ChessFriend-Fire](https://github.com/SFBrand1981/ChessFriend-Fire)

Answer (score 2):

Chessbase is top of the line, but there are a lot of alternatives: Hiarcs Chess Explorer, the Shredder GUIs, Aquarium, Chess Assistant and Chesspartner.

Arena is free, but has a few of the menu items in German, and is perhaps more for playing engines than analysis.  Other free ones are Chesspad, Kvetka, Penguin and Tarrasch.

SCID is pretty good for a free program, but the commercial ones have a lot of interesting features.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer list form, so allow a decent list that I came up with:

- CBO or ChessBase
- Fritz
- Houdini
- Komodo

are my top four picks. Although this really isn't an answer, it was too long for a comment so I posted it here.